# How could i play a local video file in python?

Tags: python, video

The following steps are to be carried out:

pick video file
and play it

tried the following code, but didn't pick video file

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('E:\Moives\Avengers.Infinity.War.mkv')
while(cap.isOpened()):
  ret, frame = cap.read()
  gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
  if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: You need to double the backslashes `'E:\\Moives\\Avengers.Infinity.War.mkv'` or use an `r` prefix: `r'E:\Moives\Avengers.Infinity.War.mkv'`. or Use slashes: `'E:/Moives/Avengers.Infinity.War.mkv'` (assuming `Moives` folder exists).

Answer (score 0):

You could use vlc module for python maybe that can solve your question

Comment: import vlc
 
media_player = vlc.MediaPlayer("E:\\Moives\\2.mp4") 
media_player.play()

Comment: tried but not showing any output or error.

Comment: Look at your directory maybe it’s movie not moive?